# ArcGIS Server Geoprocessing service for saving data

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 Pack with ArcGIS Server. 
I have two polygon feature layers and I created a model to intersect them and save output to new feature file in database. The model works then I press start.
Is it possible to create a geoprocessing service in ArcGIS server, which in given time interval takes two feature layers, intersect them and creates output? 
I tried to make it, but it seems that service does not do any work, just stands on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the GP Service to run at a "given time interval"? You don't need a GP Service. You want a scheduled task.

Many people fall into the mindset that a GP Service is needed, when actually it is not. If your requirements are simply to perform a geoprocessing operation at a given time and you don't need to have other other computers in your network or the internet be able to execute - then just schedule it with windows task manager. This [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/) has a lot of good information.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have created a script with model tool in arcmap, exported to .py file and started it on task scheduler in windows server. It's running!